# Visual Studio 2015 replace entire solution text using RegEX

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-2015, replace

Hey all I am looking for a way (if it exists that is) to replace the following:

```
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">SITE</span>
```

With this:

```
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">SITE</span></span>
```

Notice how I **added** the **< /span>** *after* the text (in order to close it).

Now my question is - how can I do this to my other 100+ html code that have different text like:

```
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">SITE</span>
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">BILLS</span>
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">AMERICAN CURRENCY</span>
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">DOLLAR</span>
etc...
```

And still be able to replace them all like:

```
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">SITE</span></span>
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">BILLS</span></span>
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">AMERICAN CURRENCY</span></span>
<span class="lbl4BoxesReq"><span class="lbl4BoxesTxt">DOLLAR</span></span>
etc...
```

I figured I could use some type of REGEX in the search to ignore the text but not sure how to go about doing all of that.

**For Tezra** update #1:

[image]

**For Tezra** update #2:

[image]

**For Tezra** update #3 FINAL WORKING:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the constraints of the file. If this is representative of the whole file, just read every line and append < /span>, no regex required. If it all looks like this, you can match with a simple

```
(<span class=".*?"><span class=".*?">.*?</span>)
```

and then the replace text is

```
$1</span>
```

(otherwise, what is the full variance of the file to know what the exceptions are?)

Comment: That regex doesn't seem to work. I have many more <span>'s in my opened project but these are the only ones with the class=lbl4BoxesTxt.

Comment: @StealthRT if the class names can change, replace "..." with ".*?". Also, this is just the regex to match. I would normally do this with Notepad++. Are you using c? c#?

Comment: @StealthRT the . is match anything the * is match 0 or more, and the ? tells the * to match as little as possible, so you need .*?. The replace text should then be $1</span>. Before running replace all, you should run findNext a couple times to make sure it is matching what you want

Comment: @StealthRT sorry, you have to surround the expression with () to put it in a matching group, so (<span class=".*?"><span class=".*?">.*?</span>)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142211/discussion-between-tezra-and-stealthrt).

Comment: That did it! Thanks Tezra! :)

Comment: Your welcome, sorry, I got confused as to what you where trying to do there for a bit =P